# A simple Transition Animation

Tags: animation, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Trying to create a simple Card Game, I want to make a **Transition Animation** which moves an `Image` from a `Canvas` point to another. How can I do this?

I wonder if such animations are available out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use a storyboard and provide start / end positions.

I show / hide text etc, change opacity etc no problems. infact all animations i used were direct port from WPDev and they work just fine.

More on them here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721608.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a Microsoft website named [.toolbox](http://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fdesign%2Ftoolbox%2F&ei=WF6FUNgPh-eYBaSvgMgC&usg=AFQjCNE9tDBllVxDSAJ0pwhWtOldNmxRhQ&sig2=WvUKEGqQ-laAwrc0_gJWzA) which contains lots of video tutorial and sample code teaching you how to create animation by Blend and visual studio 2010.
Those code samples mostly are written by Silverlight in vs 2010. I tried to compile them under vs 2012, but it failed.